# Find and list specific links in a webpage using Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

1.a  From the links present on the source code of a webpage i want to make a list of all links like "mypage.php?REF=1137988"
which is mypage.php?REF= followed by a number

1.b. However this source page also contain somethings like Supp.Form.php?REF=1137988 which i wish to avoid.

```
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
<FONT CLASS=t><TABLE cellspacing=5><TR><TD bgcolor='#FFFFA0' style='border:5px ridge lightgray'><TABLE cellspacing=4><TR><TD VALIGN=top><FONT CLASS=t2><CENTER>2015-09-03<BR><TABLE cellspacing=4><TR><TD bgcolor='#FFFFFF' style='border:4px ridge lightgray'><CENTER><FONT CLASS=t9>1137988 <A HREF='SuppForm.php?REF=1137988' target='_blank'><IMG SRC='boutons/supp.gif' width=12 height=12 border=0 TITLE='delete'></A> <A HREF='ModifForm.php?REF=1137988' target='_blank'><IMG SRC='boutons/modif.gif' width=10 height=11 border=0 TITLE='modify'></A><BR><TABLE cellspacing=4><TR><TD bgcolor='#FFFFA0' style='border:4px ridge lightgray'><TABLE><TR><TD><IMG SRC='faces/F.gif' width=36 border=0></TD><TD><CENTER><FONT SIZE=1>Age<BR></FONT><FONT SIZE=5><B>35</TD></TR></TABLE></TD></TR></TABLE></TD></TR></TABLE></TD><TD WIDTH=50%><CENTER><FONT class=t><A HREF='mypage.php?REF=1137988' TARGET='_blank'><I>
</pre>
```

Here is my code so far, which i have been trying to implement

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url = "http://wwww.somewebsite.com"

headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0' }
html = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
links = soup.find_all("a")
for link in links:
print "A HREF=mypage.php?REF=" %(link.get("a"), link.text)

print links
```

2. i also want to just put the number after REF in a list. which i will put in the numbers part of this code /
3. which means that the number that i will extract from the first list i will have to separate them all with a comma to put inside the replace =  [ ]

   ```
   template = """fjajflakjfakjfl;kj REF={}
   sklkasalsjklas
   klajsl;kdajs;djas
   aksljl;askjflka
   """

   replace = [1131062,
       1140921,
   1141326,
   1141355,
   1141426,
   1141430,
   1141461,
   1141473,
   1141477,
   1141502]

   output = [template.format(r) for r in replace]
   with open('output.txt', 'w') as f_output:

   f_output.write(''.join([template.format(r) for r in replace]))
   ```

so please help with the two things that i wish to do here. sorry if the formatting is a bit off.

thank you very much.

as suggested by @wilbur
i modified my code this is what i did

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

url = "somewebsite"

headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0' }
html = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

links = soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('.*mypage\.php\?REF=[0-9]*'))
template = """lasljasfkljaslkfj{}
slajfljasflk
aslkjfklasjflkasjf
alksjflkasjf;lk
"""

replace = [ link.split("=")[1] for link in links ]

output = [template.format(r) for r in replace]

print output
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    f_output.write(''.join([template.format(r) for r in replace]))
```

Comment: I found the error and updated my answer, have a look and let me know if it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

The following will grab all the links that match your description and then get the REF parameters from each and put them into replace.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url = "http://wwww.somewebsite.com"

headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0' }
html = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
links = soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('.*mypage\.php\?REF=[0-9]*'))

replace = [ link['href'].split("=")[1] for link in links ]
```

Comment: replace = [ link.split("=")[1] for link in links ]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
>>>
>>> output = [template.format(r) for r in replace]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'replace' is not defined
>>>

Comment: >>> print output
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'output' is not defined
>>> with open('output.txt', 'w') as f_output:
...     f_output.write(''.join([template.format(r) for r in replace]))
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'replace' is not defined

Comment: Sir, this is the op that get when i use ur code. pls suggest improvements.

Comment: <a href="mypage.php?REF=1132887" target="_blank"> in this comment < > is stored the desired number. Idk perhaps that is interfering with the code?

Comment: dear @wilbur thank you very much for your reply. it helped me a lot.

Comment: @krishna Awesome, glad I could help! If this was a good answer to your question, you should accept it: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers