# Scrape a list of numbers from the source code of a webpage in Python and output to text file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am a 3 day old python user.

1. I want the program to read a website source
2. and then copy just a set of numbers that appear after the `=` sign only for links that are like
   `<a href="mypage.php?REF=2327327"></a>`
3. Then I want to put them in a list (in a subsequent code block) which will take each number from that list
4. And put each number in the list into a templated paragraph.
5. Then I want to output such paragraphs to a text file.

The desired output is

```
5646556
6564654
454654
4646546
```

and so on

This is the code i am working with.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

url = "somewebsite"

headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0' }
html = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

links = soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('.*mypage\.php\?REF=[0-9]*'))
template = """lasljasfkljaslkfj{}
slajfljasflk
aslkjfklasjflkasjf
alksjflkasjf;lk
"""

replace = [ link.split("=")[1] for link in links ]

output = [template.format(r) for r in replace]

print output
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    f_output.write(''.join([template.format(r) for r in replace]))
```

Here was the other half of the original program.
This program just takes numbers from a list that you have to type, and it puts each of those numbers in a paragraph and then copies that paragraph with the next number being inserted from the list.

```
template = """fjajflakjfakjfl;kj REF={}
sklkasalsjklas
klajsl;kdajs;djas
aksljl;askjflka
"""

replace = [1131062,
    1140921,
1141326,
1141355,
1141426,
1141430,
1141461,
1141473,
1141477,
1141502,
1141525,
1141622,
1141662,
757053,
989967]

output = [template.format(r) for r in replace]

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    f_output.write(''.join([template.format(r) for r in replace]))
```

Comment: Break your sentence. It's very hard to understand what you wanna achieve?

Comment: @AhsanulHaque7 i have added to the question with breaks

Answer (score 0):

to get the number just use split

```
st = "mypage.php?REF=23273273"

_, number = st.split('=')

print(number)
```

23273273

Comment: ur answer seems to be the right one. But pls tell where to put this in my code ? can u pls copy paste it in the right place and write. ty.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you should check out my updated answer to your last question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32658529/find-and-list-specific-links-in-a-webpage-using-python/32660184#32660184), because if you don't, this code will just throw the same error we previously discussed. That will correctly give you the values for the `replace` list. Your `output` assignment will also work fine, but when you try to join all of your paragraphs, they'll run together. You should join them with a newline character (`\n`). This means that the last portion of your code should read like this:

```
template = """lasljasfkljaslkfj{}
slajfljasflk
aslkjfklasjflkasjf
alksjflkasjf;lk
"""

replace = [ link['href'].split("=")[1] for link in links ] # note the added ['href']

output = [ template.format(r) for r in replace ]

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    f_output.write('\n'.join(output)) # we don't need to re-make the list, and join on \n
```